# Can a employer not allow their employees to be off when they are sick

Tags: professionalism, working-conditions

I am working for this company and just started in November. I have doctors appointments that were premade and they will not allow me to go to them and if i do i get written up. You are not allowed to take breaks during the day, not allowed to call off if you are sick without getting in trouble. If you child is sick you are not allowed to take off to be with them or go get them from school even if you have no one else to get them or watch them. You are only given 3 sick days for the whole year no time off for personal time. The sick days have to be for you and not anyone else in the family. I had a fever today and had to call off i went to the doctor and got a doctor note but still got in trouble. I also had doctors appointments which i went to on my lunch at work and came back to work but got in trouble for going to those as well. Can an employer do this to you.. There are other situations at this job that i would also like to talk about. i do not think that they way that they conduct their business is fair and do not think that they treat their employees fair. how to go about doing something about this and finding a new job

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for legal advice which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Check with your State Department of Labor if you are in the US, or as @scaahu mentions, your local labor bureau if you work abroad. This is from the NYC Departmet of Consumer Affairs: http://www.nyc.gov/html/dca/downloads/pdf/MandatoryNotice.pdf

Comment: Where is this taking place?

Comment: It may be wrong; but in your shoes I'd be strongly tempted to punctuate my resignation with [ipecac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrup_of_ipecac).

Comment: My previous comment may sound too extreme, so I took it out (i used the word "slave"). I apologize if it causes any confusion. I was suggesting to contact local labor bureau. I do have another question for the OP: You keep saying _getting in trouble_. What kind of trouble did you get? Hours reduced? Salary reduced? Or something else?

Comment: @leagle67 Can you [edit] your question so that is not a wall of text? It is in your interest to make your question understandable and easy to read.

Comment: which country are you working in - though this rights to sick pay  is a legal Q

Comment: In my country this would be outright *illegal*. As you don't seem to be from Germany, get legal council. If it's legal in your country, go and vote for a party that *makes* it illegal to treat people that way. In the meantime, get a job that's better than just "not illegal".

Comment: @leagle97 How many employees does the company employ? If they are past a certain number of employees, then there are certain laws they are bound by if in the United States

Answer (score 7):

You're obviously working for an employer who doesn't know how to treat their employees.  **You should immediately start trying to finding another position elsewhere.**  Places like this need to be driven out of business.  I suggest writing reviews to warn off other potential employees on sites like [glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com) and even [yelp](http://www.yelp.com) and the like to warn off customers.

You can also continue to go to work and collect your paycheck without much fear in the short term because you really have nothing to lose.  If they do fire you then you may have a case for wrongful termination depending on the state and local laws where you live (I am not a Lawyer).  There's no point worrying about the write-ups since you'll have a new job soon anyway.  Keep doing as good of a job as you can under the circumstances until you are able to get that new job - it's always best to leave with a clear conscience and there may be other employees that you work with in the future.  Two weeks notice is a luxury that a company like this doesn't deserve (assuming you work in an at-will employment state), you can let them know in writing the day you start the new job.

As much as you may desire to seek revenge, leaving and other civil means of running them out of business are the best, safest, and most professional.  I'm hoping Dan's comment about ipecac is an attempt at humor.  **You need to leave with your integrity intact and your head held high.**

Comment: Wrongful termination is at the discretion of a judge, so you should remove the reference.  In any event I don't believe there are any federal laws about sick time off and few states might have such laws.  If the illness is not classified as a disability then most likely there would be no recourse here.

Comment: @Andy - Good point, though I just softened the language about wrongful termination instead of eliminating it since that is something to consider.

Comment: I think you'd be best off removing the reference.  Its extremely unlikely to be correct: http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/wrongful-termination-was-firing-illegal-32282.html